# Dealing with memory errors. Getting more errors as i try to figure out the issue. Tried cleaning slots with q-tip and rubbing alcohol, it got worse

Tags: memory, crash, memtest, memtest86

Computer specs idk if helps
https://pcpartpicker.com/user/WaldoTheRanger/saved/BQqHGX
(Not actually a mining rig. Card was never used for that)

Had some screen flickering at random times for a couple of days, then a full on crash to desktop playing a 10 year old game

Roommate recommended memory test

It found just one, 1 bit error two times

https://www.flickr.com/photos/144302197@N05/53297669111/in/dateposted/

https://www.flickr.com/photos/144302197@N05/53296797902/in/dateposted/

Then I started removing sticks to see which one was the issue

First tested 2 sticks in slots 3 and 4, it passed

Tested the other two sticks in the same slots since I knew those slots were for sure working and to remove variables

It passed this time too

Confident the sticks were fine and it was a problem with either slot 1 or 2, I tested both of those individually

I had limited time though, and wanted to get it done sooner, and so only ran for 3 passes each before quitting them prematurely and going to the next one

But there were no errors for either in 3 passes

This is when my roommate suggested I try cleaning out the slots, as a speck of dust could potentially be the issue

I used a q tip and 91% Isopropyl, had to feather out the end of the q tip to get it to stick in about halfway down

It came out with some gunk on it, but hard to tell it that was on the contacts or the tops of the slot

Also cleaned the contacts on the sticks

Around this time I had also turned off xmp in hopes it was a power draw or silicon lottery issue

I then put everything back together (maybe i didn't wait long enough? I thought you didn't have to worry about that with Isopropyl) and ran another test with all sticks

This one froze halfway through with 79 errors and a message about how my computer might be susceptible to high frequency hammer bit flips

https://www.flickr.com/photos/144302197@N05/53298045149/in/dateposted/

Ran it again now changes to the configuration, hoping it was a fluke, woke up today to ~150 errors with a completed test

https://www.flickr.com/photos/144302197@N05/53297917628/in/dateposted/

So

I have no clue what I'm doing

My roommate has a little better idea, but I would appreciate some third opinions

Currently giving a full 4 passes on slots 1 and 2 again. Will update with those results

I will also test 3 and 4 again after that to confirm the rubbing alcohol q tip didn't screw anything up

Also aware of the possibility that it was just a seating issue in the last two tests, and I didn't take them out and put them back in before the second one, just wiggled them to make sure they were all the way in

But then where did the first errors come from?

More possibly important context

This computer has been around for several years now, started with only 1 8gb stick, at the beginning of this year I added one set of the 2x8 in the build above, about 2 to 3 weeks ago I added the second one, swapping out the mismatched other stick

About a week and a half to two weeks after that I started seeing the screen flickering

Comment: 1. Static electricity could have *permanently* damage memory when being removed, handled or inserted. 2. Cotton swabs shed lint, which could cause poor contact. Clean slot with dry *lintless* material. 3. Try removing memory and leaving out mismatched or bad sticks.